# multiple end points for uploading files to multiple locations

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

What I am trying to achieve is if a user drops multiple files to a drop area and based on the files types, js code will create multiple amazon endpoints. I haven't seen any method or way where I can create multiple end points.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Krishna

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`setEndpoint` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-s3.html) of the S3 Fine Uploader within the `submitted` event to check the filetype and modify the endpoint when each file is submitted to the uploader.

```js
function getBucketPathFromFileType (fileName) {
    // your logic for determining the s3 bucket
    // from the file type goes here.
    return bucketUrl;
};

var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
   // snippet ...
   callbacks: {
        onSubmitted: function (id, name) {
            var bucketPath = getBucketPathFromFileType(name);
            this.setEndpoint(bucketPath, id);
        });
   }
   // snippet ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works perfectly. Meanwhile I have one more question here, I am creating dynamically endpoints for images if there is any error on creating endpoint file any file then that particular file should not get uploaded. I mean how we can remove it from list of files which are going to be uploaded?

Comment: If there's an error generating an endpoint, couldn't your server just return a response indicating that?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your message. I am generally end points for each dropped files and if there is any error while generating endpoint for a specific then I want to remove this file from the list of uploading files. mean I dnt want to upload that file . Here its uplaoding all the files and as endpoint is not correct hence the failure message. I guess there must be some way to remove a particular file from the list of file before upload.

Comment: Could you ask a separate question? I _think_ I know what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure. Be sure to include all relevant client-side code. That way I can provide an answer with code.

Comment: Why would there be an error generating the endpoint? I'd be concerned with that working correctly since it sounds like an integral part of your app.

Comment: Yes you are right. but there are scenerios when there will be errros in few points. and I want to show them near to each file.

Comment: Mark, I have added my updated code now. please see and let me know if there is any way for my problem.

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt, looks like you mistakenly added your code to my answer to this question rather than opening up a new question. Just post a new question, make sure to tag it with 'fine-uploader', explain what you're trying to do the best you can, put in your client-side code and anything else that may be relevant, and we'll try to provide an answer as soon as we can.

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt, and if my answer to this question is *right*, please accept it :)

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt, I think I understand your issue. Check out the [`cancel` method in the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html). You should just be able to do `cancel(id)` and that file will not be uploaded and it will be removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Let me try and I will let you my progress on this.